# Möller-Trumbore false positive result in specific point

Tags: c++, algorithm, intersection

I copied code from this [whitepaper](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~gfx/Courses/2003/ImageSynthesis/papers/Acceleration/Fast%20MinimumStorage%20RayTriangle%20Intersection.pdf) and i can't figure out while it gives me false-positive intersections.

Here's problematic values:

Triangle points: (100.0, 100.0, 100.0), (-100.0, 100.0, 100.0), (-100.0, 100.0, 50.0);

Ray origin point: (0.0, 98.0, 50.0);

Ray direction point: (-100.0, 5.88235, 73.5294).

This points gives me an intersection when it shouldn't.

Here's my implemetation:

```
#include <iostream>
#define EPSILON 0.000001
#define CROSS(dest, v1, v2) \
    dest[0] = v1[1] * v2[2] - v1[2] * v2[1]; \
    dest[1] = v1[2] * v2[0] - v1[0] * v2[2]; \
    dest[2] = v1[0] * v2[1] - v1[1] * v2[0];

#define DOT(v1, v2) (v1[0] * v2[0] + v1[1] * v2[1] + v1[2] * v2[2])
#define SUB(dest, v1, v2) \
     dest[0] = v1[0] - v2[0]; \
     dest[1] = v1[1] - v2[1]; \
     dest[2] = v1[2] - v2[2];

int intersect_triangle(double orig[3], double dir[3],
                    double vert0[3], double vert1[3], double vert2[3],
                    double *t, double *u, double *v) {
    double edge1[3], edge2[3], tvec[3], pvec[3], qvec[3];
    double det, inv_det;

    // find vectors for two edges sharing vert
    SUB(edge1, vert1, vert0);
    SUB(edge2, vert2, vert0);

    // begin calculating determinant - also used to calculate U parameter
    CROSS(pvec, dir, edge2);

    // if determinant is near zero, ray lies in plane of triangle
    det = DOT(edge1, pvec);

    if (det > -EPSILON && det < EPSILON)
        return 0;
    inv_det = 1.0 / det;

    // calculate distance from vert to ray origin
    SUB(tvec, orig, vert0);

    // calculate U parameter and test bounds
    *u = DOT(tvec, pvec) * inv_det;
    if (*u < 0.0 || *u > 1.0)
        return 0;
    //prepare to test V parameter
    CROSS(qvec, tvec, edge1);
    //calculate V parameter and test bounds
    *v = DOT(dir, qvec) * inv_det;
    if (*v < 0.0 || *u + *v > 1.0)
        return 0;
    // calculate t, ray intersects triangle
    *t = DOT(edge2, qvec) * inv_det;

    return 1;
}


int main() {
    double orig[] = {0.0, 98.0, 50.0};
    double dir[] = {-100, 5.88235, 73.5294};

    double vert0[] = {100.0, 100.0, 100.0};
    double vert1[] = {-100.0, 100.0, 100.0};
    double vert2[] = {-100.0, 100.0, 50.0};
    double* u;
    double* v;
    double* t;

    if(intersect_triangle(orig, dir, vert0, vert1, vert2, u, v, t))
    {
        std::cout << "Intersect" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Doesn't intersect" << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Another implementation of this algorithm tells me that intersection is in (-34, 100, 75).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT1: Looks like an intersection...**

I've just plugged that triangle and origin/ray direction into a plotter and it looks like there is an intersection:

[image]

Are you sure about expecting it not to intersect with these values?  Are you mistaking orig/dir here as end/begin points rather than origin and direction?

**Original**

Möller-Trumbore usually works only with triangles that have counter clockwise winding (unless you test both windings, I think thats whats the CULL testing is about in that paper...)

Comment: It's should work both ways. Ray is any case doesn't intersect triangle.

Comment: @gusdak I think those points do cause an intersection, see edit

Comment: Wow! Can you give me a link to this plotter? Can't find one, that drew without equation. It's very likely that there is an intersection, but in hundreds of pictures that i drew, my corrupted mind didn't see it.

Comment: @gusdak I plotted it with matplotlib3d and python.  You can check out the script [here](https://trinket.io/python3/b189e86dc2).  If you are new to python I recommend installing [anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads)

Comment: So i figured out my mistake. Dir point is actually not point in which we want to trace ray, it's only direction, as it's name says. Can u say how I should trace ray to a specific point?

Comment: intersection point = orig + t * dir